# Can the review queues respect ignored tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, tags, reviewing

While still playing through Bioshock Infinite, I have the tag ignored to avoid any spoilers.  While going through the review queue, I came upon a question asking, Why did X happen during the ending?  I didn't read much of the question, and luckily it was well spoiler tagged, but that's the entire reason I put the tag on ignore!  I do have Hide Ignored Tags checked.

Do I need to just avoid the review queue until I'm done playing the game, or is there another option somewhere to do this, that I've just not found?

Comment: I think there's a good argument for this even not taking spoilers into account. If I'm ignoring a tag because I have no interest/knowledge, I shouldn't really be editing questions in that tag anyway.

Comment: This happened to me too on that question about the game's ending. I was able to avert my eyes from it and ninja-click on 'Skip', though. Anyone know if there are Greasemonkey scripts or browser extensions that could ignore questions and its answers with a specified tag in the review queue?

Comment: If you think this is bad, try moderating...  I *can't* ignore them, although I tend to stick my fingers in my ears and go LALALALALALALA when I view the question so as not to get spoiled.

Comment: Given that you can filter for *only* certain tags, surely filtering *out* certain tags should be considered too.

Comment: This has recently been marked [status-planned] by SE Staff on Meta.SE: [Review Queues and Ignored Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178378/179041), following suit here.

Answer (score 10):

So you can filter to only review *certain* tags, but not to exclude tags. Not ideal, but it's all we've got for now.

[image]